# Shall I Grant privileges for replication slave on the db?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have just set up a MySQL replication slave, with some point-in-time backup of the master.

I granted REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE privileges for the replication account at the external IP address of the slave machine, on both the master host and the slave host, as recommended in *High Performance MySQL, 3rd Ed*. And the slave was set as `read_only`, as well.

The slave host is an Azure instance, with different internal IP address and external one, and is located not very near from the master host physically.

When I tried to start the slave, errors occurred.

The result of `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` says that `Slave_IO_Running` is `Yes` but `Slave_SQL_Running` `No`. And it seems that the relay logs has been written but it is still not replicating the master.

And the last error (errno 1036) is apparently complaining that a table in the db is read only.

My guess is that I should grant more privilege to the replication slave account.

EDIT:

This issue is caused by enforcement of SELinux policy. My DB was copied from a cold backup, and the SELinux context for that directory and files was not properly configured. See [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,17008,236746#msg-236746).

Comment: OK, it's actually an issue caused by SELinux. Please vote for close of this question.

Comment: You can always delete your own question unless it has many good answers